# What data structures for python are used to save user input data( usernames, their passwords, etc.)

Tags: python, data-structures

I know it is probably hard to give an exact answer but anything will help so I appreciate the help. I’m new to this and I happened to start with learning python. I’ve gotten pretty good with the the basics (strings, lists, tuples, dictionaries, etc) and I’ve started playing with classes as well but not much. Im having trouble though seeing what each one is best used for to solve real world problems (like what data is Best for strings, what’s best for tuples, what’s best for lists, etc.). I’ve tried to read a few articles on this but none of them really helped. Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with `what data is best for strings etc` I think you kinda answered it in the question.  Strings store strings, lists store lists etc., when you use them is really up to how you design something.

Answering your title, storing usernames/passwords can be as easy coding them in a string or storing them in a local file. Going to assume you don't want an actual solution like hashing and storing in remote database. Unless you are releasing something for public use, don't worry about this too much and just start with a simple implementation.

When your just getting started (and long after that tbh) just follow the rule of 'if it works it works'. You'll learn as you go and get better.  If you keep progressing, every couple months you'll look back and be like, 'wow I can't I believe I wrote this trash'. Side note -> when your starting out with classes try to plan out how everything is going to work together before you start coding, you will save yourself some frustration.

If you want to try and make something cool with python, try PyGame, https://www.pygame.org/news, has tons of user tutorials.

Lastly, work on your google skills, there is a ton of information that pops up if you just type `how to store usernames and passwords in python` or `implement username and password in python`. Even `username and password in python` in youtube is giving me some good results.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I didn’t really word the question that well. I was trying to figure out some real world uses for each of the ones I entered. For example how does Facebook use lists? How does sales force use strings? The reason I gave the username and password example is because I tried using a code I found on google and it only stores one username and password. I’m just trying to understand the typical uses for each. I know it’s probably hard to give them “best uses” since there is so much you can do but I was jw. Thank you for that website too I’m definitely going to try that out.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the best way to store username and password would be to use a dictionary in python. You can use it simply like so:

```
user_details = {"username": "Wolfe", "password": "wolfe123"}
```

I like to use a dictionary because this is the easiest format to manage any sort of database. It is also the easiest to convert into JSON format for API queries.

As for your second query, yes you can make web apps in python very easily with Django and Flask. There is also a new python framework for making mobile apps called kivy. But keep in mind it's relatively new.

> - Find the Django documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/).
> - See the Flask documentation [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/).
> - You can see the kivy documentation [here](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/).

Hope this helps :)

Comment: your approach does not scale, imagine you have 2 (two) users, what your `user_details` dictionary will look like?

Comment: This dictionary is for a single user. If you want to store multiple users, you would have to use a list of dictionaries to sore the different users. You can even use a nested dictionary for this.

Comment: Thanks for the help! This will definitely help. Do you know a way to store it for many users? I know this is dumb considering how new this is to me and I still have a lot to learn, but I’m trying to build a basic app just for me that lets someone sign up, sign in, and read a text or enter a text (kind of like putting notes in that I could later read). I just can’t find anything that gives real world examples. And the ones I’ve found keep giving me error messages.